# Цифры 2 и 4 в именах функций

Tags: php, javascript, java, c#, терминология

Часто встречал у разных разработчиков, в названиях методов использую числа 2 или 4

Например:

camelCase2UnderScore
processUrl4VSect

несет ли это какой-то информативный характер? или для чего так именуют? Чаще всего это числа 2 или 4... ?

Comment: -- Why is 6 afraid of 7? -- Because 7 8 9.

Answer (score 10):

Это английские созвучия. Цифра 2 (Two) похожа на слово To. А цифра 4 (Four) - это созвучно For.

Стиль скорее неформальный, как и различные сокращения. Вы вот может быть знаете, что U - это сокращение от You, а musm - это miss you so much, но в нормальных компаниях такое не особо принято, разве что в качестве неофициальных пасхалок.

Comment: хороший пример тут будет штатный `nl2br()` в пхп, заменяющий новые строки (`N`ew_`L`ine) `\n` на тэг `<br>`

Comment: Широко известная либа `log4j` туда же